# How to get nested Child from Firebase Database Using Android?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to get list of all Allowed child from this type of JSON Tree:

```
databaseRef.child('Users').child('Allowded').addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

@Override
public void onDataChange (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

  //
  }
}

@Override
public void onCancelled (DatabaseError databaseError) {

} };);
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried anything? If you have, then mention it on your question and tell on which step did you fail. A lot of us want to help you but please read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Anyway, welcome to StackOverflow :)

Comment: Also: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: Yes it is possible yo resolve please watch your id it will not match your app id

Answer (score 2):

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference userRef = database.getReference("users").child(key).child("Alloweded");
ValueEventListener postListener = new ValueEventListener() {
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    User userObj = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);

}

@Override
public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    // Getting Post failed, log a message
    Log.w(TAG, "loadPost:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
    // ...
}
};userRef.addValueEventListener(postListener);
```

> User is your Model class which have lat, lng, name,no., profileUrl etc

*Try this I hope it works fine.*

Answer (score 1):

**Firebase listeners fire for both the initial data and any changes.**

If you're looking to synchronize the data in a collection, use ***ChildEventListener***. If you're looking to synchronize a single object, use ***ValueEventListener***. Note that in both cases you're not "getting" the data. You're synchronizing it, which means that the callback may be invoked multiple times: for the initial data and whenever the data gets updated.

```
FirebaseRef.child("message").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
 @Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
  System.out.println(snapshot.getValue());  //prints "Do you have data? You'll 
    love Firebase."
 }
@Override
 public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {        
}
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
databaseRef.child('Users').child('Allowded').addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

@Override
public void onDataChange (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

   for (DataSnapshot childDataSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: 1    " + childDataSnapshot.getKey());
            for (DataSnapshot childDataSnapshot2 : childDataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: 2    " + childDataSnapshot2.getKey());
            }
   }

  }
}

@Override
public void onCancelled (DatabaseError databaseError) {

} };);
```

Comment: Welcome, and thank you for the contribution. While it’s acceptable to provide code-only answers, it’s often more useful for the community if you can also provide an explanation of the code and help people understand _why_ it addresses the problem. That often reduces the amount of follow-up questions, and can really help new developers understand the underlying concepts.