# Is there any way to retrieve data in Firebase without updating the values in database?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to retrieve the value from Firebase database without adding or updating any value.

I tried using every listener, but they all need data to be updated for retrieving values.

Comment: [Answer of this question is help you check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41591045/how-to-get-nested-child-from-firebase-database-using-android/41591763#41591763)

Comment: Thanx , but the listener used will deliver the data which is changed. I want  values without changing any value to my database.@Vijaymakwana

Comment: which code did you assume changing your database value?

Comment: [This might help you it get the data at once](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17904613/how-to-read-data-from-firebase-once-using-java-android)

Comment: thanx for replying @koceeng .. i have my answer for now :)

Comment: Thanx @Vijaymakwana for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you attach a Firebase listener it immediately values for the existing value and then fires again for any changes. So you don't need to change the value to have the listener fire.

From the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#listen_for_value_events):

> You can use the `onDataChange()` method to read a static snapshot of the contents at a given path, as they existed at the time of the event. **This method is triggered once when the listener is attached** and again every time the data, including children, changes.

Answer (score 0):

If it can help//

> My solution about this is to unregistered the Firebase listener and
>   then register it again.