# How to acces to attribute in database Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

I want to get NomDirection but it does not work for me,any help plzzz?!!

```
 Fdatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Fondation").child("Directions");
Fdatabase.orderByChild("NomDirection").addValueEventListener(new com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        //final List<String> etab = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            namedirection = (String) child.child("NomDirection").getValue();
            //  etab.add(namedirection);
            Toast.makeText(testFondation.this,namedirection,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `.getReference().child("Fondation").child("-KrjG...").child("Directions")`.

Better lookin `.getReference("Fondation/-KrjG.../Directions)`.

So you need to insert your key, which starts with "KrjG..." in your case, into the query.

Comment: ohh yes sorry, for the mistake here, I Already added this child but it stell doesn't working!! :(

Comment: @IkramLaaroussi Hi. Did u check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41591045/how-to-get-nested-child-from-firebase-database-using-android? It will work for you.

Comment: @IkramLaaroussi U can check in link how data retrieved with key and value

Comment: @IkramLaaroussi Did u check link ?